# Network Error while Posting data in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm learning Angular 4. I tried to post a file along with a keyword. While uploading I get the following error in the web page console.

*code: 19
columnNumber: 0
data: null
filename: "http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js"
lineNumber: 5291
message: "A network error occurred."
name: "NetworkError"
result: 2152923155*

This is how I'm trying to upload the file.

**Method in .service file**

```
  url: String = 'localhost:8080/file-uploader/rest/file/';

      getFileName(fileToUpload: File, columnHeading: any) {
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          })
        };
        const body = {
          file: fileToUpload,
          columnHeading: columnHeading
        };
        return this.http.post<UploadResponse['path']>(this.url + 'upload', body, httpOptions);
      }
```

**Interface File**

```
interface UploadResponse {
  path: string;
}
```

**File Upload Typescript File**

```
  uploadFile() {
    this.httpService.getFileName(this.file, this.columnHeading).subscribe(
      res => {
        localStorage.setItem('filePath', res);
      }
    );
  }
```

**File Upload html Tag File**

```
<div>
  <input type="file" [(ngModel)]="file" name="file">
  <br>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="columnHeading" name="columnHeading">
  <br>

  <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
  <button (click)="uploadFile()">
    Upload File
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What the value of `this.url`? And this should be more like `return this.http.post<UploadResponse['path']>(this.url + '/upload', body, httpOptions);
`

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question with those values.